# Display source codes's logic operations of and or in in their raw forms

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

Upon transmitting source code to org-mode

```
 #+begin_src python
class Solution0:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        ....
        dummy = cur = ListNode(0)

        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val <= l2.val:
            ....
       cur.next = l1 or l2
        return dummy.next      
#+end_src
```

The org mode display the  logic `and` and `or` as ^ and V

How could configure it display them in raw form.

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `prettify-symbols-mode`, eg. interactively, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `prettify-symbols-mode`.  Alternatively, remove the symbols for "or" and "and" from the `prettify-symbols-alist` in your python mode hook (or disable the mode there).

See `prettify-symbols-mode` and `python-prettify-symbols-alist` for more details.